# How to determine whether a nonempty set of a vector space is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that a subspace of a vector space like $\mathbb R^3$ would be $\mathbb R^2$ and a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is a vector space like $\mathbb R^1$ but my question is, how would I determine whether a subset is a subspace of a vector space? I understand that I would have to use the 2 closure properties which states that a scalar times the vector would have to be in $S$ (the subset) and a vector $x$ plus a vector $y$ would have to be in the subset $S$.

Here is a mathematical representation of the 2 closure properties

1) $a * x$ is in $S$, whenever $x$ is in $S$ for any scalar $a$

2) $x + y$ is in $S$, whenever $x$ is in $S$ and $y$ is in $S$

Here is an example problem that I have encountered that I do not know how to prove.

$$ S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) | x_1 = x_2 \}$$

Question: How would I know if this subset was a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint:Take $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ s.t. $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the axioms:

1. Looks like the 0 vector is in your set. This is pretty clear.
2. Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ be in your set.  Their sum is $(x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$.  But since they are in your set, then $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. So then their sum is $(x_1+y_1, x_1+y_1, x_3+y_3)$, and so their sum is in your set.
3. Scaling any element yields an element in your set.  This is trivial to see.

Looks like a subspace to me.

Answer (score 0):

1st property$\Longrightarrow$A=$\left\{ a,a,c\right\} $and B=$\left\{ b,b,d\right\} $where
A,B$\epsilon$S.

A+B=$\left\{ a,a,c\right\} $+$\left\{ b,b,c\right\} $=$\left\{ a+b,a+b,c+d\right\} $$\epsilon$S.

2nd property $\Longrightarrow$$\alpha$A$\Longrightarrow\alpha$$\left\{ a,a,c\right\} $$\Longrightarrow$$\left\{ \alpha a,\alpha a,\alpha c\right\} $$\epsilon$S.